# How do I optimize this simple SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple and straightforward SQL query that is taking over 100 seconds to complete. There are about 10,000 rows of data in the table being searched. What can I do to speed up this query?

The table structure that the query is searching is..

```
id (int 10)
forumId (varchar 255)
username (varchar 255)
email (varchar 255)
timestamp (int 10)
```

For example the query is..

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE forumId = 'minecraft' AND username = 'test'
```

It is taking over 100 seconds

Comment: Any indexes on your table?  Can you show an execution plan?

Comment: `forumId` could be an `ENUM`. You could also add an index to `forumId` and `username`.

Comment: For only 10k records, I would suspect there's some locking or something going on - a table-scan shouldn't take that long. Unless your rows contain large BLOBs or something?

Comment: ^there is something else definitely going wrong other than your query and table structure (not that those are wrong).

Comment: The indexes fixed it. The issue was due to using utf8 encoding on 4 or 5 255 var char columns per row and overloading resources. Dropping the 255 var char to 150 and adding indexes made the query time drop from 100+ seconds to 0.00XX

Comment: forumId should be an int

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a great read.

Comment: forumId is actually a textual identifier

Answer (score 7):

add compound index,

```
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX(forumId, username)
```

also lower your string length to about 75 `:)`

Comment: +1 I hate dealing with multiple string filters, compound index is the best way at the moment.

Comment: `+1` for the index, but I don't believe lowering the string length should increase performance (though I'm not a mySql expert)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: ["Filesort uses a fixed-length row-storage format similar to that used by the MEMORY storage engine. Variable-length types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) If the OP ever sorts that table, and MySQL chooses to use filesort, MySQL will build a structure on disk that takes 255 characters for each of those columns. That can lead to a *lot* of disk I/O.